# Searching for a specific row using a form to get data and getting the detailed result in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to create a simple website for Hospital Management System using Cakephp. I want a search method in my Patients' controller which will generate a form and take the PatientID as input from the user. It will then generate the result of all the values for that particular row. How do I go about it and what changes do I need to make in the model,controller and template?

The PatientsTable is as follows:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('patients');
    $this->displayField('Patient_ID');
    $this->primaryKey('Patient_ID');
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('Patient_ID', 'create');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('Name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('Name');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('Address', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('Address');

    $validator
        ->date('DOB')
        ->requirePresence('DOB', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('DOB');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('Contact');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('Gender', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('Gender');

    $validator
        ->allowEmpty('Blood_Group');

    return $validator;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into one of the awesome plugins for searching in CakePHP already made, eg. https://github.com/friendsofcake/search.

Then all you would need is this:

Initialize method in table class:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('patients');
    $this->displayField('Patient_ID');
    $this->primaryKey('Patient_ID');

    // Add the behaviour to your table
    $this->addBehavior('Search.Search');

    // Setup search filter using search manager
    $this->searchManager()
        ->value('Patient_ID');
}
```

Example controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg', [
        'actions' => ['index']
    ]);
}

public function index()
{
    $query = $this-> Patients
        ->find('search', ['search' => $this->request->query]);
    $this->set('patients', $this->paginate($query));
}
```

Then you can simply use a URL query parameter like /patients/index?Patient_ID=14 to show only patients with that value in Patient_ID.

This can be done with the CakePHP form helper:

```
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('Patient_ID');
echo $this->Form->button('Search', ['type' => 'submit']);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Discalimer: I stole all the example code from: https://github.com/friendsofcake/search

You should check out different types of filters to use in the table, those are awesome to know: https://github.com/friendsofcake/search#filters - and as always, read the readme file! :-)

Good luck searching and filtering!